# Having issue with name of special characters in email address

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, httpresponse

During scraping of this [page](https://www.lieferando.de/speisekarte/fame-burger-berlin), Below is how I am getting a response

```
In [14]: headers                                                                
Out[14]: 
{'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
 'Host': 'www.lieferando.de',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0',
 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1}

In [15]: url                                                                    
Out[15]: 'https://www.lieferando.de/speisekarte/dreamburger-pizza'

In [16]: fetch(scrapy.Request(url,headers=headers))                             
2021-03-10 16:19:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.lieferando.de/speisekarte/dreamburger-pizza> (referer: None)
```

But the issue is that whenever I tried to extract an email address, I am not getting desired email string. You'll get my point through below code

```
In [18]: email = ''.join(response.css('div:contains("E-Mail")::text').getall()).strip().split('E-Mail')[-1].split(' ')[-1]                            

In [19]: email                                                                                                                                        
Out[19]: 'info&commat;lieferando&period;de'
```

I want to have an email like `info@lieferando.de` and the same things happens with the `name` field i.e

```
In [20]: jsn = json.loads(response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]::text').get())                                                             

In [21]: jsn.get('name')                                                                                                                              
Out[21]: 'Dreamburger &amp; Pizza'
```

How can I get rid of those special character names?

Comment: Have you tried `email.replace("&commat;", "@").replace("&period;", ".")`?

Comment: @ForceBru, Yes, I tried with dict and for loop but I thought that was not an efficient solution

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) in the standard library e.g.

```
>>> import html 
>>> html.unescape('info&commat;lieferando&period;de')
'info@lieferando.de'
>>> html.unescape('Dreamburger &amp; Pizza')
'Dreamburger & Pizza'
```